# Distinct topologies on continuous functions $(L_p$ spaces restricted to $C[0,1])$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

I am trying to show that the topologies $\tau_p$, $\tau_q$, $\tau_{\infty}$ ($1\leq p<q$) induced by the metrics 
$$\delta_p(u,v)=\left(\int_0^1 |u-v|^p\right)^{1/p}\quad \delta_q(u,v)=\left(\int_0^1 |u-v|^q\right)^{1/q}\quad \delta_{\infty}(u,v)=\sup_{[0,1]} |u-v|$$
on $X=C[0,1]$ are distinct.

To get an idea of the topologies I proved $\tau_{\infty}\subset \tau_q\subset \tau_p$, so this boils down to finding a set in $\tau_p$ that is not in $\tau_q$ and one in $\tau_q$ that is not $\tau_{\infty}$.

The issue I keep running into is that any open set in one seems to be open in the other because we can always find an open ball around any $f\in$ the topologies. Can someone help me out?

Comment: HInt: If it has the same topoligies, then it have the same continuous functions.

Comment: the continuity on $[0;1]$ implies $||u||_{\infty} < \infty$ so they are the same, but their respective completion for each norm (which is not reduced to the continuous functions anymore) are different.

Comment: To show that $\tau_\infty \neq \tau_p$, can't you note that $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0, 1]$ converges in the $\ell_p$ norm to the zero function, whereas there's no sup limit?

Comment: @BalarkaSen Hm I am confused. Doesn't the pointwise limit on $\ell_p$ not converge in $C[0,1]$ either?